# Issues in reading file in AxAcroPDFLib

Tags: c#, pdf, adobe

I am working on displaying pdf file on **{AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF}**.
I have already reinstalled my AdobeReader after sometimes its gives error again.

I really don't understand what to do.
If there is any solution please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

```
 pdfReader.src = (@ip + "\\" + dt.Rows[0]["Path"].ToString()).Replace("\\", "//");
                            pdfReader.Tag = (@ip + "\\" + dt.Rows[0]["Path"].ToString()).Replace("\\", "//");
                            pdfReader.Show();
```

Comment: Initialization order is very important for ActiveX controls.  That Show() call is very fishy, the control should be made visible by adding it to its Parent's Controls collection.  Like it is normally done in InitializeComponent() when you use the designer.  If that is not done correctly then you will get this exception.  The snippet is entirely inadequate to tell why you wanted to do it this way and to propose a solution.

Comment: I have modified my code and  added **pdfReader.CreateControl()** in **InitializeComponent()** it gives class not registered error ..what should i have to do.

Comment: That is just another liability with this control, you need to have the correct version of Adobe Reader installed.  It is miserable control and worth considerably less than what you paid for it.  There are a *lot* of PDF viewer libraries out there, you need to go shopping.

Comment: After 2-3 days the same problem came.. Is there any permanent way to prevent reinstallation of AdobeReader again and again.

Comment: AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF also gives error on window XP..